# using stmt = db:prepare and stmt:bind_values to Insert date and a number in to a table

Tags: sqlite, lua

in
if a table is created in the following way

```
db:exec [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tips_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,time TIME,date DATE, counter INTEGER)]]
```

and data is inserted as below into the above table

```
local stmt = db:prepare [[INSERT INTO tips_table (time, date, counter) VALUES (?, ?, ?);]]

stmt:bind_values(os.date('%H:%M:%S'), os.date('%y/%m/%d'), counter)
```

Why am I getting the following error

`lua: Test.lua:247: attempt to index local 'stmt' (a nil value)`

I played around with different variable and tried to convert the date and time to strings.

I looked at the lsqlite3 syntax from different websites and endlessly Googled, but I cant seem to get it right

Comment: you need to specify the "sqlite" library

Comment: You should wrap `db:prepare` in `assert` in order to get an error if preparing a statement fails. The error message will then tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Lua, it is necessary to check that the returned object is not nil, before calling its methods.

Your `db:prepare` returned nil. Is suppose it's because you had not supplied `id`, which is a primary key not accepting null.

Comment: @Alexandra, I am new to this Lua and Sql thing. So how would supplying an id look like in code. because I tried local stmt = db:prepare [[INSERT INTO tips_table (NULL, time, date, counter) VALUES (?, ?, ?);]] and that still did not work

Comment: Sorry, I am not now sure now that it because of `id`. Seems that sqlite automatically makes a field of the type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (`id` in your table) an alias for always existing `ROWID`, which is `AUTOINCREMENT` and therefore needs no explicit assignment, although its uniqueness is not guaranteed. However, `NULL` is column's name, not value; and there should be as many columns as values; so, try this: `INSERT INTO tips_table (id, time, date, counter) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
local stmt = db:prepare [[INSERT INTO tips_table (id, time, date, counter) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);]]
stmt:bind_values(os.date('%H:%M:%S'), os.date('%y/%m/%d'), counter)
```

@Alexander the above code works. Thanks for the help